# How do I count the number of quotes in a file using python?

Tags: python, text-processing

I have a plain research paper text file and I am asked to count the number of quotes in that file using Python. How would I go about doing this? Is there a way to count the number of occurrences of the character `"` in the file?

Answer (score 2):

This short program will do:

```
import sys
print(sum(line.count(sys.argv[1]) for line in sys.stdin))
```

One-liner and usage:

```sh
python3 -c 'import sys; print(sum(line.count(sys.argv[1]) for line in sys.stdin))' '"' < data.txt
```

An arguably simpler, non-Python solution based on `tr` and `wc` would be:

```sh
tr -c -d '"' < data.txt | wc -c
```

If there's at most one match per line you can also use `grep` in “count” mode:

```sh
grep -cFe '"' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [count(](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count)) it returns the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences